# Outlook 2011 Conditional Formatting

Tags: ms-office

I'm having a hard time differentiating between the "bold" unread messages and read messages in my inbox.  I would like to be able to make unread messages a different color (e.g. red)...is this possible?  I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on further research and discussion, it sounds like this feature does not exist at the current time.

Answer (score 2):

I have not found an automated way to do what you are asking in Microsoft Outlook for Mac 2011.

A (very) manual way would be to create a category named Read and assign it a color that contrasts well with black. As you read your email, categorize each as Read. Then the text of your read email would be colored to match the category color. Again, this is not the optimum way to manage email.

If someone knows a better way I am interested to read it.

Comment: Thanks, if you're also interested in a better solution, why not upvote my question so that it gets more attention?

Comment: @AJ. Upvoting questions does not bump them up the front page. Only comments, editing, and answers do that.